# WordPress Multisite - show "parent" pages and posts on "child" sites

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I created multisite network with subdomains and added pages and posts on primary site. I want show this pages and posts on child sites. For example, *primarysite.local/test-page/* and *sub.primarysite.local/test-page/* show content from *primarysite.local/test-page/*.

By default, *sub.primarysite.local/test-page/* show Error 404 page, because this page is not exists.

I tried to use **parse_query** and **pre_get_posts** actions to check page url in primary site and override default behavior but it was not successful.

Maybe someone has an idea of what kind of hook should be used or is not possible to implement in WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result, I decided to use the hook **template_redirect**.

Code of plugin for posts and pages:

```
<?php

/*
  Plugin Name: Global posts
 */

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'global_posts_redirect' );

function global_posts_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->is_404() && !is_main_site() ) {
        //switch to primary site for checking post/page
        switch_to_blog( 1 );

        $slug = $wp_query->query_vars[ 'name' ];

        $args = array(
            'name'           => $slug,
            'post_type'      => 'any',
            'post_status'    => 'publish'
        );

        $my_posts = get_posts( $args );

        if ( $my_posts ) {
            //if post/page exists - change header code to 200
            status_header( 200 );

            $post        = $my_posts[ 0 ];
            $post_type   = get_post_type( $post );

            //emulate wp_query
            $wp_query->queried_object_id = $post->post_id;
            if ( $post_type == 'page' ) {
                $wp_query->query[ 'pagename' ]       = $post->name;
                unset( $wp_query->query[ 'name' ] );
                $wp_query->query_vars[ 'pagename' ]  = $post->name;
            }
            $wp_query->query_vars[ 'name' ]  = $post->name;
            $wp_query->queried_object        = $post;
            $wp_query->post_count            = 1;
            $wp_query->current_post          = -1;
            $wp_query->posts                 = array( $post );
            $wp_query->post                  = $post;
            $wp_query->found_posts           = 1;
            if ( $post_type == 'page' ) {
                $wp_query->is_page = 1;
            } else if ( $post_type == 'post' ) {
                $wp_query->is_single = 1;
            }
            $wp_query->is_404        = false;
            $wp_query->is_singular   = 1;

            restore_current_blog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you alter this code to detect and then go to a custom post type single page?